# Trying to use the result of one prepared statement into another insert statment

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I googled for a while and even through i like to answer my own questions i thought it would be best to ask the quest for future Googler's

My SQL is a little rusty and i want to use a select statement that searches for the company id so i can then use that id in an insert statement so i don't have to use the company name but the id instead.

i have tired a all in one statement as well as using an include but im not sure if the variable from one PHP script can see the other or how to properly include that variable in the insert statement

Thanks in advance :)

```
<?php

include "login.php"; 

$binbarcode = isset($_POST["binbarcode"]) ? $_POST['binbarcode'] : '0000';
$bintype = isset($_POST["bintype"]) ? $_POST['bintype'] : 'empty';
$bincompany = isset($_POST["companyname"]) ? $_POST['companyname'] : 'IWE';
$client_clientid = isset($_POST["client_clientid"]) ?     
$_POST['client_clientid'] : '27';

include "Fetchcomp.php";    

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO bin(binbarcode,   
bincompany,   bintype, client_clientid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")or   
die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssi", $binbarcode, $bincompany, 
$bintype, $client_clientid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

////////Fetchcomp

```
<?php
include "login.php"; 

$companyname = $bincompany;

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT clientid FROM client WHERE  
companyname = ? ")or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "i", $client_clientid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: If you include the `Fetchcomp.php` before your query, then your connection is null, as you have `mysqli_close($con);` at the end, so your `INSERT` query will fail. Also, you are including `login.php` twice, once in your code and again in `Fetchcomp.php`.

Comment: Yeah thanks but kinda new that sorry wrote it at 4am was more wondering how to put the result from fetchcomp into main script? as im getting an error  expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given